# Patches in seaborn

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

My intention is to add a patch at a specific coordinate in seaborn's `lmplot` :

[image: Intended seaborn plot with patch]

Is there anyway to add a rectangular/square patch to `lmplot`?

I was able to get the plot printed out through `sns.lmplot()`. But when I try to add the rectangular patch using `ax.add_patch()` statement with relevant coordinate's, it error's out.

```
#Sample code to generate lmplot  and add patch   
ax= sns.lmplot('A', 'B', hue="group", data=res_me,fit_reg=False, \
              palette="Set1",size=10, aspect=1, scatter_kws={"s": 100,"linewidths":2,"edgecolor":"black"})

ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((0.912, 0.72), 1.02, .802,fill=False,edgecolor='green',lw=3))
```

I get the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'add_patch'
```

So can we add patches to `FacetGrid` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lmplot` as you've learned, returns a `FacetGrid`, which stores all of its axes in an `axes` property as a 2D numpy array.

So you just need to do something like:

```
fg = sns.lmplot('A', 'B', hue="group", data=res_me,fit_reg=False,
              palette="Set1",size=10, aspect=1,
              scatter_kws={"s": 100,"linewidths":2,"edgecolor":"black"})

fg.axes[0, 0].add_patch(patches.Rectangle((0.912, 0.72), 1.02, 
                        0.802,fill=False,edgecolor='green',lw=3))
```

Note that if your `FacetGrid` only has one `Axes` object in it, you can access it directly with `fg.ax`

Comment: @chuck is this solved your problem, please let future visitors to this site know by marking this as an accepted answer