# Add patch to Seaborn jointploint

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, seaborn

I have created a patch and want to apply it to a jointplot in Seaborn. When I go to try to apply the patch, it either splits the plots into two graphics or, if I change the `kind` attribute in the jointplot function from `kde` to anything else, it throws an error `inner got multiple values for keyword argument 'ax'`.

When I try to apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271907/patches-in-seaborn), the variable `fg` does not have the attribute `axes` and it does not work.

In the code below, if I use `kind = "scatter"` and omit the `ax`, I get a blank output then the jointpolot. If I use `kind = "scatter"` and add `ax = ax`, I get the above mentioned error. If I use `kind = "kde"` and `ax = ax`, I get the following images:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

My code:

```
import descartes
import fiona
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from shapely.geometry import shape
import pandas as pd
import time
#
start_time  = time.time()
input_csv   = r"C:\path\to\a\csv\with\coordinates.csv"
shapefile   = r"C:\path\to\a\fun\shapefile.shp"
df          = pd.read_csv(input_csv, delimiter = ",")
df          = df[df["Latitude"] > 37.70833]
lat         = "Latitude"
lon         = "Longitude"
fig         = plt.figure()
ax          = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon = False)
shp         = fiona.open(shapefile)
pol         = shp.next()
geom        = shape(pol["geometry"])
un_sf       = geom.envelope.symmetric_difference(geom)
un_sf_patch = descartes.PolygonPatch(un_sf)
ax.add_patch( un_sf_patch )
my_fig      = sns.jointplot(x = lon, y = lat, data = df, color = "grey", kind = "scatter")
end_time    = round(time.time() - start_time, 5)
print "Seconds elapsed: {0}".format(end_time)
```

**How can I add the patch to my Seaborn jointplot in a single graphic?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A seaborn `jointplot` creates its own figure, together with 3 axes.

```
g = sns.jointgrid(..)
g.ax_joint   # big axes in the middle
g.ax_marg_y  # marginal axes
g.ax_marg_x
```

Here you want to add your patch to the `ax_joint`.

```
g = sns.jointgrid(..)
g.ax_joint.add_patch( un_sf_patch )
```

Comment: I added `my_fig.ax_joint.add_patch(un_sf_patch)` and received the error `Can not put single artist in more than one figure`. Googling around and checking similar errors, I am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Sure, you need to not create the other figure at all and especially not to add the patch to it.